# Can I use a hidden wedge tenon joint in 2"thick pine?

Tags: mortise-and-tenon

The plan is to take some live edge pine, chop a square mortise in it, and use a hidden wedge in the tenon of the legs (poplar 1.5").

Is this too thin? Unnecessary? It would be for side tables.

Comment: If I understand what you're aiming to do a question leaps to mind, *why*? Why introduce an unnecessary complication that gives you basically one shot at getting the legs installed, annnnd they can never be removed without breaking something....

Comment: Good question. What would be a better way to go?

Comment: There are zillions ways of attaching legs/leg assemblies to a tabletop. OK not zillions but more than a few. I was going to ask if you can do a quick back-of-an-envelope sketch of the table you're building for a new Question asking how you might attach the top, but there are numerous existing Q&As which cover this. The search here works great, do a search for "attach tabletop" and you'll find various options you can pick from (many work about equally well, you just choose one you like or can get locally) but also related info about allowing for seasonal movement that you may benefit from.

Comment: Maybe show a simple isometric drawing of the join you want to make. This will help you organize your design and help us fully understand the question details.